# Exercise for the face muscles

Tags: anatomy

Do exercises for the face muscles actually change it? I know that they won't reduce the fat locally, but if our face muscles are like other muscles, they should adapt to a higher load. So is it all hogwash or do some of the work?

Comment: I can't see why they wouldn't, but I also don't see why you would want to.

Comment: @DeeV well you could improve it in the same way you improve your abs.

Comment: I believe there are physical therapists with specific training in this area.  Worth a try!

Comment: You mean any special exercises? For the moment it can be answered with - `yes, they change it`. How much? That is other question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, facial muscles are capable of growing. However, training them is different from standard strength training. Because of their location and function, it can be hard give them a good challenge without some know-how. A quick google search of "training facial muscles" will yield some examples of such exercises.

Because the training style will differ from traditional strength training, you should expect differing results with the muscles in your face. Which is to say that it will take longer for them to grow, and their growth potential is smaller than your bigger muscles. It should however be noted that their small size and placement actually makes the small changes in size ironically more notable.

---

https://www.mensfitness.com/training/pro-tips/facial-exercises-look-younger-and-get-muscular-jawline

From that article, here is a list of all the exercises that were mentioned. Each group of exercises were designed by different experts.

> **—Group 1—**
>
> 1. Eye Squeeze
>
>    - Directions: Pull your lips down to tighten your face (like the scream character), then pull your lips to the right, and squeeze one eye closed for one second (in a pulsing manner) ten times. Repeat with the opposite eye.
>    - Muscles worked: The muscle surrounding your eye; when tightening the eyes, you’re pulling the skin, but you’re not wrinkling it.
>    - Duration: 3 sets of 10, rest, then another 3 sets of 10
> 2. Jawline Roll
>
>    - Directions: With your face tightened (as if you’re about to get punched), pucker your lips and move them to the right. Now, with your jaw tense, say with force, “EW Charles.” "Speaking aloud ignites the muscle quicker," says Georgesku. And make sure to not grind your teeth.
>    - Muscles worked: Here, you’re pulling up the muscle underneath the jawline. When you say “EW Charles,” your tongue draws a circle in your mouth and the resistance works the jaw.
>    - Duration: 3 sets of 10, rest, then another 3 sets of 10
> 3. Tongue Press
>
>    - Directions: Place your tongue on the roof of your mouth, right behind your teeth. Then add tension by tightly pressing your tongue to completely close the roof of your mouth, and begin making the noises “mh mh mh mh.” “It’s very important to make the humming/vibrating sound when performing these exercises because they assist the muscles,” says Georgesku.
>    - Muscles worked: This will target sag underneath the chin.
>         
>        Duration: 3 sets of 10, rest, then another 3 sets of 10
> 4. Brow lift
>
>    - Directions: With your hands in the shape of a closed peace sign, place your finger nails (not your fingertips) over each brow and apply pressure to push your eye brows down. Then, while pushing that skin down, gently push your brows up and down, and repeat.
>    - Muscles worked: Here, you’re creating a weight (the pressure of your finger nails) to lift the eyes and build the muscle in your forehead.
>    - Duration: 3 sets of 10, rest, then another 3 sets of 10

> **—Group 2—**
>
> 1. Clenching
>
>    - Directions: Clench and hold your teeth together for 3 seconds while using a special mouth guard made by your dentist—not a sports mouth guard. The soft plastic material on this guard will prevent TMJ problems and protect your joints.
>    - Muscles worked: The jawline area
>    - Duration: 3 sets of 10
> 2. OO-EE
>
>    - Directions: Open your mouth and purse your lips together without your teeth touching or showing, then say “OO, EE” in exaggerated movements. You can also do “OO, AH” movements.
>    - Muscles worked: This will target the muscles around the mouth, on the sides of the lips, and between the nose and upper lip.
>    - Duration: 3 sets of 10
> 3. Sagging Chin
>
>    - Directions: Place your elbow on a table with your fist under your chin. Then try to open your mouth while exerting force with your wrist to create resistance. Hold then release.
>    - Muscles worked: Underneath the chin and jawline area.
>    - Duration: 3 sets of 10

> **—Group 3—**
>
> 1. The Lower Jowl Lifter Routine
>
>    - Directions: Place your right hand on your collarbone and wrap your bottom lip over your bottom teeth. Then, tilt your head back a couple inches while using your facial muscles to pull the corners of your mouth back (with your bottom lip still covere.) Hold, then release your head back down with your eyes still looking upward. Repeat on the other side (left hand on collarbone.)
>    - Muscles worked: The jawline area
>    - Duration: 4 sets of 10 (5 right and 5 left)
> 2. Jawbone Restorer
>
>    - Directions: Place both thumbs side-by-side at the tip of your chin with your other fingers resting below each ear. Then, push your chin into your thumbs to create resistance, and slide your thumbs along the jawbone, with medium pressure, ending just below each ear.
>    - Muscles worked: the jawline area
>    - Duration: 10 times
> 3. Double Chin Slide
>
>    - Directions: Place the palm of your hand under your chin, and with your mouth closed, stretch your lower jaw down as far as you can. Then, exert pressure with your palm as you slide your hand along the double chin area, the jawline, and the side of the face ending at your temples.
>    - Muscles worked: underneath the chin
>    - Duration: 10 times (5 right and 5 left)
> 4. Cheek Firmer
>
>    - Directions: Place the length of your index finger below the eye along the upper cheekbones. Then open your mouth as wide as comfortable, curl your lips over your bottom teeth, and smile with the corners of your mouth to create flex, then release.
>    - Muscles worked: the jawline area
>    - Duration: 40 times

Comment: Why did it get downvotes?  He didn't  say anything that doesn't make sense... are people downvoting based on the argument or because they dislike the person?

Answer (score 0):

I know that with using a lot of chewing gum, you can develop bigger chewing muscles. And actually that is a problem - at least with musculus masseters. They do not get smaller. Bigger muscles influence on your skull, and brings pain.

Getting back to the question. They can get bigger, if putted under higher load, but not always bigger is better. Be sure you know what you are doing, sometimes that can be really tricky.